# How to securely add user to mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, credentials

So I am in the middle of building my first database. I understand that to connect, I type

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password') or die("Couldn't connect");
?>
```

I would like to allow users to register to my sql server with their own user and password credentials. Then they would be able to own their own database with their information. After doing some research I found that these two ways seem to add users to the mysql.users table:

```
mysql_query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password';");
mysql_query("CREATE USER '$username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;");
```

I don't quite understand the difference between the two and maybe someone could direct me to an answer. When I run either query nothing happens. When I run this SQL statement I get a new user, but it does not work through the query:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user`(Host,User,Password) VALUES('localhost','$username','$password')");
```

Can I get some help figuring this issue out?

Comment: don't use mysql, it is deprecated and will be removed. Use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: @michael-st-clair I looked at PDO and it did not seem to work well with phpmyadmin. I am assuming mysqli will work similarly and not be compatible.